# Uploading to a remote server using PHP/CURL

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

Using PHP/CURL, how to upload a file to a remote server wherein the user must be logged in first?

thanks

Comment: What kind of authentication must pass between client and server?  Htaccess or otherwise?

Comment: Standard HTTP basic authentication? form-based login? captchas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [cUrl Login then cUrl Download](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987876/curl-login-then-curl-download)

Comment: see also [search: php curl upload after login](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php%20curl%20upload%20after%20login)

Comment: @macki added an edit to show you how to send post data using CURL

Comment: @macki do you have any questions?  EDIT: to clarify you want to make curl --data "birthyear=1905&press=%20OK%20"  match the variable expecting login name and password and make sure they are correct.

Answer (score 0):

FYI CURL can pass authentication credentials along like this:

```
curl --user USER:PASSWORD -s http://localhost:4848/monitoring/domain/server/transaction-service
```

But it depends on what the server is expecting.

EDIT:
Here's how to send POST data:

```
    curl --data "birthyear=1905&press=%20OK%20"         http://www.example.com/when.cgi
```

Please ask if you have any questions.