# Need help logging to remote site with PHP using cURL

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to log into the following site remotely using cURL but I am having trouble.
http://www.cbssports.com/login

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?  Thank you.

```
<?

$url = 'http://www.cbssports.com/login';
$fields = array(
            'login_form::userid'=>urlencode('USERNAME'),
            'login_form::password'=>urlencode('PASSWORD')
        );

foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
$fields_string = rtrim($fields_string,'&');

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);
curl_setopt ($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Comment: Probably a cookies/sessions issue. Have you configured cURL to make persistent calls to the website?

Comment: possible duplicate of [cUrl Login then cUrl Download](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987876/curl-login-then-curl-download)

Comment: how would i go about configuring cURL to make persistent calls to the website?

Answer (score 0):

The from has a lot of hidden fields, there's a good change that one or all of these are required (see trimmed version of the form below).

```
<form method="post" action="/login/index" name="login_form" id="login_form" >
<input type="hidden" name="dummy::login_form" id="dummy::login_form" value="1">
<input type="hidden" id="form::login_form" name="form::login_form" value="login_form">
<input type="hidden" value="http://www.cbssports.com/login" name="login_form::xurl" id="xurl">
<input type="hidden" value="150" name="login_form::master_product" id="master_product">
<input type="hidden" value="cbssports" name="login_form::vendor" id="vendor">
<input type="text" value="" name="login_form::userid" id="userid" size="30" maxlength="50" data-field-required="1">
<input type="password" value="" name="login_form::password" id="password" size="30" maxlength="12" data-field-required="1">
<input type="submit" value="Sign In" class="formButton">
</form>
```

Comment: They're also posting to the wrong URL - you can see in the form tag the action is */login/index*

Comment: I added all of the hidden fields and revised the URL as suggested but still cannot get the code to log in

Comment: `$url = 'http://www.cbssports.com/login/index';
$fields = array(
            'dummy::login_form'=>urlencode('1'),
            'form::login_form'=>urlencode('login_form'),
            'login_form::xurl'=>urlencode('http://www.cbssports.com/login'),
            'login_form::master_product'=>urlencode('150'),
            'login_form::vendor'=>urlencode('cbssports'),
            'login_form::userid'=>urlencode('USERNAME'),
            'login_form::password'=>urlencode('PASSWORD')
        );`

Comment: They may be checking the referrer (ie. the page you've come from) which obviously is not set when using cURL

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Firefox, I recommend you do a dummy post using LiveHTTPHeaders, just to check all the post fields.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I was fiddling with the same thing using .NET.  Here is what the content string will look like in the POST request (using C# string concatenation):

```
"dummy%3A%3Alogin_form=1&form%3A%3Alogin_form=login_form&login_form%3A%3Axurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cbssports.com%2Flogin&login_form%3A%3Amaster_product=150&login_form%3A%3Avendor=cbssports&login_form%3A%3Auserid=" + userID + "&login_form%3A%3Apassword=" + password
```

Notice that the miscellaneous hidden fields will also need to be in there.  The additional catch I ran into was that the response has more than one cookie that you'll need for the subsequent GET request.  Thus, you'd need to use some kind of container rather than appending a single "Set-cookie" header.  That will not work and your output stream will simply return the data from the main page you're redirected to.

Hope that helps someone.